# SpringMVC & @ModelAttribute peculiarities

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jstl, el

Using Spring/SpringMVC 3.0.5 I've defined a method in my controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(params = { "save","!delete" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveFoo(...
    @ModelAttribute("vo") @Valid DescriptionBuilderVO vo, BindingResult result) {
    ...
    result.rejectValue("foo.sequenceNumber", "foo.builder", new Object[]{vo.getFoo().getSequenceNumber()}, "Sequence Number too high");    vo.getFoo().setSequenceNumber(originalNumber);
    return new ModelAndView(WebConstants.VIEW_BUILDER, "vo", vo);
```

Notice that I'm attempting to set a value in the VO object inside the controller.  The funny thing is that if I do this with @ModelAttribute the new value doesn't show up.  If I remove @ModelAttribute from the method contract, the new value appears exactly as you would think.  The problem comes when there are errors, the only way to get the errors is to have the @ModelAttribute in the contract.

BTW my HTML looks like:

**HTML**

```
<form:input path="foo.sequenceNumber" id="sequenceNumber" size="4" maxlength="4"/>
<form:errors path="foo.sequenceNumber" cssClass="ui-state-error" />

foo.sequenceNumber = the value the user typed in; when I use @ModelAttribute
foo.sequenceNumber = the value I set in the controller; but I lose any errors
```

It seems to me that SpringMVC is putting the ModelAttribute VO into a "special" place and passing it back to the jsp but not in an obvious location.  Does anyone know how I can get at the VO object in this situation?

Comment: Have you tried adding `@SessionAttributes("vo")` as an annotation on the controller class?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It's entirely possible that this might give me something I can use but I'm trying to figure out at a more architectural level what's going on.  Is it either a peculiarity of Spring, a bug, or perhaps my own iognorance?

Comment: Do you have @RequestMapping annotation over class or saveFoo method?

Comment: Yes I do.  The code is getting executed it just isn't setting the same VO variable that the JSP is pulling from.  BTW I did explicitly add the new VO to the session and that comes back with the correct values which just makes me more confused.  How is it that the input is still showing the old value?  It just make now sense.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear with question. Which did you annotated,  class OR method (with @RequestMapping)?

Comment: @kasdega I think its a Spring quirk.  [Here's some possibly helpful documentation.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html)

Comment: @mgamulin I just updated the question with your answer...@RequestMapping is on the method not the class.

Comment: @Pat this is the closest anyone has come to explaining what is going on.  Still doesn't help me get at the real VO but at least it means I won't go crazy figuring it out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried many different things including the reordering the Valid and ModelAttribute annotations and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

In reading the documentation suggested by Pat in the comments it does refer to a special context where the VO is stored.  Anyway, if you're trying anything similar to this I suggest you go about it in a different way perhaps building a completely new VO and passing it back to the view, which is what I did.

Answer (score 1):

wierd. The same thing works for me. The only difference i see is the order of Valid and ModelAttribute
can you try reversing the order of Valid and ModelAttribute?

```
public ModelAndView saveFoo(...
   @Valid @ModelAttribute("vo") DescriptionBuilderVO vo, BindingResult result) {
}
```

BTW, which version of spring are you using?

Comment: Excellent question, I should have included that...I'm using spring 3.0.5

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I will give this a shot and see what happens.  BTW is there any best practice or guide line to what order the @'s are in?

Comment: This didn't change anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try naming your object "descriptionBuilderVO", like the following:

```
@Valid @ModelAttribute("descriptionBuilderVO") DescriptionBuilderVO descriptionBuilderVO, 
BindingResult result)
```

I know it shouldn't be this way, but I've found problems when the name of the object is different than the class name.

Note that you'll also have to change the name of the object in your jsp:

```
<form:form commandName="descriptionBuilderVO"
```

...etc...